# CODEIGNITER Fatal error : call to a member function num rows on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables

Below tho code of the relative file:

Message:

> Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean Filename:
>   libraries/Datatables.php Line Number: 399

```
$this->load->library('datatables');
    $this->datatables
   ->select('check_in.id, check_in.barcode_num, check_in.station, date')
   ->from('check_in')
   ->join('(select id, check_in.barcode_num, max(date) as ts 
            from check_in group by check_in.barcode_num) j', 'j.barcode_num 
            = check_in.barcode_num and check_in.date = j.ts', 'inner join');
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

I have searched for the answer but didn't found the relevant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A boolean query return means that your query is failing and thus `num_rows()` `result()` `row()` whatever... won't work.

You can identify the error in your SQL by going into the database configuration file and turning on db debug.